# how to put multiple values in an option?

Tags: html

I have a select with values like van, economy, economy-citroen. I select the van option and it displays the vans, however I would like to make an option that calls the van and economy values at the same time (not the multiple select version).

Something like value="economy van".

```
<select id="car_type" class="car_type span12">
<option value="-1" selected="selected">Any</option>
<option value="economy">Economy</option>
<option value="economy-citroen">Economy</option>
<option value="premium">Premium</option>
<option value="standard">Standard</option>
<option value="van">Van</option>
</select>
```

I would like to make it like:

```
<select id="car_type" class="car_type span12">
<option value="-1" selected="selected">Any</option>
<option value="economy">Economy</option>
<option value="economy-citroen">Economy</option>
<option value="premium">Premium</option>
<option value="standard">Standard</option>
<option value="van">Van</option>
<option value="van economy">Economy Van</option> ---so it displays both the economy and vans
</select>
```

Comment: Show some actual code and explain what you mean by “calling” something.

Comment: The code posted does not do anything. It is simply a menu where an option can be selected, without any effect. Show what you are really doing with the data.

Comment: i want to make it work thru the html (im newbie to php and mysql)...how is it possible to have option value= van and economy in the same time?

Comment: i would like to modify this theme: http://bizzthemes.com/preview/?theme=2808 ....after you have picked the date, its time to pick a car...and there i would like to get so two types are displayed in the same time

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
<select multiple>
   <!-- options here -->
</select>
```

Using this, you'll be able to select multiple options for that select element.

To read more on the HTML element `select` please refer the Mozilla Developer Network's document

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Comment: i see...but i would like so i create a link like economy van...without the user needing to select double...because visually would look confusing....and there will be like 6 different options

Comment: No, it won't be visually different. It would just let the user select two elements. If user wants to select only 1 value, he can still select only 1 value :)

Comment: ok so basically the values will mean cars...and i want to make it so i just call the type of the cars....like <option value="skoda citroen hyundai">economy</option>

Comment: Then once it will be passed to the server, it would be simple as `select_name=skoda citroen hyundai`. All these three values would be sent to server!

Comment: is there somewhere a guide where i could make it? it seems so simple, yet so complicated

Comment: Only because you're a newbie to HTML. Keep learning and you'll get to what you want to do! :)

Comment: The request, in the question, to “make an option, which calls the van and economy values in the same time” is vague and even obscure, but it cannot mean *this* (which means that the user needs to select two options).

Comment: http://bizzthemes.com/preview/?theme=2808 the step 2 process where the vehicles are selected..i want to make so two categories are displayed

Comment: I have already told you, that is JavaScript's job to handle the Client's events such as click, change, submit etc. You cannot do that using HTML or CSS.

Comment: This should be it:
 // Filter cars
  $("#car_type").live('change',function(){
    filterVehicleList();
  });
  $(".car_sort").live('change',function(){
    sortVehicleList();
  });
  $(".car_extras_check").live("click", function() {
    fillVehicleExtrasArray();
    $(this).parent("div").parent("li").toggleClass("selected");
  });
  $(".extra_count").live("change", function() {
    fillVehicleExtrasArray();
  });

Answer (score 0):

Add [the `multiple` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-select-multiple) to the select element.

Comment: thanks for the reply...i would like to so there is only one option which calls more values...is not that possible?

Comment: For that you'll need JavaScript to dynamically add more data or HTML to the document. Changing the whole of the Select ELEMENT.

Comment: is it a lot complicated?